# WPF Objectbinding of Collection

Tags: wpf, listview, binding, taskbar

I have a taskbar-application developed with WPF, where I just can't figure out how to bind my collection of objects with Objectbinding to a TrayPopUp.

Here's my collection class. It is created on startup and filled with objects by deserializing a xmlfile (with fillCollectionFromXml-method):

```
public class OrdreCollection
{
    // Fields
    private ObservableCollection<Ordre> _ordreList = new ObservableCollection<Ordre>();


    // Properties
    public ObservableCollection<Ordre> OrdreList
    {
        get
        {
            if (_ordreList == null)
            {
                return new ObservableCollection<Ordre>();
            }
            return _ordreList;
        }

        set
        {
            _ordreList = value;
        }
    }


    //Methods

    public void fillCollectionFromXml(String filepath)
    {            
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Ordre>));
        using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(filepath))
        {
            OrdreList = xs.Deserialize(rd) as ObservableCollection<Ordre>;
        }
    }

    public void createXmlFromCollection(OrdreCollection oCol, String filepath)
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Ordre>));
        using (StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(filepath))
        {
            xs.Serialize(wr, OrdreList);
        }
    }

    //public OrdreCollection getOrdrer(String filepath)
    //{
    //    OrdreCollection Ordrer = new OrdreCollection();
    //    Ordrer.fillCollectionFromXml("@../../Data/Ordrer.xml");

    //    return Ordrer;
    //}
}
}
```

Base-classes:

```
[Serializable]
public class Ordre : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // INotifyPropertyChanged Member
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void Notify(string propName) {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }

    // Fields
    private DateTime ordreDato = DateTime.Today;
    private int ordreReference = 561978;
    private String bestiltAf;
    private List<OrdreItem> ordreItem;

    //Constructors

    public Ordre() { }

    public Ordre(DateTime ordredato, int ordrereference, String bestiltAf, List<OrdreItem> ordreItem)
    {
        this.Ordredato = ordredato;
        this.Ordrereference = ordrereference;
        this.BestiltAf = bestiltAf;
        this.OrdreItem = ordreItem;
    }


    //Properties

    public DateTime Ordredato
    {
        get { return ordreDato; }
        set { 
            ordreDato = value;
            Notify("OrdreDato");
        }
    }

    public int Ordrereference
    {
        get { return ordreReference; }
        set { 
            ordreReference = value;
            Notify("Ordrereference");
        }
    }

    public String BestiltAf
    {
        get { return bestiltAf; }
        set { 
            bestiltAf = value;
            Notify("BestiltAf");
        }
    }

    public List<OrdreItem> OrdreItem
    {
        get { return ordreItem; }
        set {
            ordreItem = value;
            Notify("OrdreItem");
        }
    }


    //Methods

    public void addItem(OrdreItem item)
    {
        OrdreItem.Add(item);
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class OrdreItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // INotifyPropertyChanged Member
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void Notify(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }

    // Fields
    private String produktKode;
    private String produktNavn;
    private DateTime kalibreringsDato;
    private DateTime leveringsDato;
    private int antal;

    // Constructors
    public OrdreItem() { }
    public OrdreItem(String produktKode, String produktNavn, DateTime kalibreringsDato, DateTime leveringsDato, int antal)
    {
        this.produktKode = produktKode;
        this.produktNavn = produktNavn;
        this.kalibreringsDato = kalibreringsDato;
        this.leveringsDato = leveringsDato;
        this.antal = antal;
    }

    //Properties
    public String ProduktKode
    {
        get { return produktKode; }
        set {
            produktKode = value;
            Notify("ProduktKode");
        }
    }

    public String ProduktNavn
    {
        get { return produktNavn; }
        set {
            produktNavn = value;
            Notify("ProduktNavn");
        }
    }

    public DateTime KalibreringsDato
    {
        get { return kalibreringsDato; }
        set { 
            kalibreringsDato = value;
            Notify("KalibreringsDato");
        }
    }

    public DateTime LeveringsDato
    {
        get { return leveringsDato; }
        set { 
            leveringsDato = value;
            Notify("LeveringsDato");
        }
    }

    public int Antal
    {
        get { return antal; }
        set {
            antal = value;
            Notify("Antal");
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my XAML:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:tb="clr-namespace:Hardcodet.Wpf.TaskbarNotification;assembly=Hardcodet.Wpf.TaskbarNotification"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Models"
                    x:Class="WpfApplication1.Resources"
                    x:ClassModifier="public"
                    >
    <!-- Globaly declared OrdreCollection. Contains a list of orders.-->
    <local:OrdreCollection x:Key="OrdreList"></local:OrdreCollection>

    <!-- Globally declared notify icon -->
    <tb:TaskbarIcon x:Key="MyNotifyIcon" 
                    IconSource="/Icons/ge256x256new.ico" 
                    ToolTipText="GE Ordre Management"
                    PopupActivation="LeftOrDoubleClick"
                    DataContext=" "
                    >
    <!--
    We can use arbitrary UI elements as ToolTips.
    Let's use a semi-transparent border.
    -->

        <!-- Set a simple popup  -->
        <tb:TaskbarIcon.TrayPopup>
            <Border
                Background="White"
                BorderBrush="Orange"
                BorderThickness="2"
                CornerRadius="4" Margin="0" Padding="10">
                <GroupBox Header="Bestillinger" Height="Auto" Name="BestillingGroupBox" Width="445" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="10">
                    <Grid>
                        <!--<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="ordreDato"/>-->
                        <ListView IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding OrdreList}">
                            <ListView.View>
                                <GridView>
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Ordredato" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Ordredato}" />
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Navn" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=BestiltAf}" />
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Ordrenummer" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Ordrereference}" />
                                </GridView>
                            </ListView.View>
                        </ListView>
                    </Grid>
                    <!--<Grid>
                        <Grid.DataContext>
                            <XmlDataProvider Source="@../../Data/employees.xml" />
                        </Grid.DataContext>
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="OrdreTemplate" DataType="Ordre">
                                <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="Orange" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="4" Margin="0" Padding="10" Width="400">
                                <TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock FontWeight="bold">Antal: </TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=Antal}" />
                                <TextBlock FontWeight="bold">Produkt: </TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=Produkt}" />
                                <LineBreak></LineBreak>
                                <TextBlock FontWeight="bold">Dato:</TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=Dato}" />
                                <LineBreak></LineBreak>
                                <TextBlock FontWeight="bold">Bestilt af:</TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=BestiltAf}" />
                                <LineBreak></LineBreak>
                                <TextBlock FontWeight="bold">Leveringsdato:</TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=TilLevering}" />
                                <LineBreak></LineBreak>
                                <TextBlock FontWeight="bold">Ordrenr.:</TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=OrdreNr}" />                            
                            </TextBlock>
                                </Border>
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        </Grid.Resources>

                        <ListBox                         
                        Name="treeView" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.,XPath=/Ordrer/Ordre}"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource OrdreTemplate}" Background="white"
                        BorderBrush="Black"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        Padding="4" />
                    </Grid>-->
                </GroupBox>
            </Border>
        </tb:TaskbarIcon.TrayPopup>
    </tb:TaskbarIcon>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The problem is with TrayPopup. This I would like to show the values of all Orders in my OrderCollecion in a listview/listBox. I hope my question is understandable and that my code isn't too messy. I can make it work when I fill a listbox with a XmlDataProvider, but not with a ObjectdataProvider or directly from a collection.

Comment: All your code has `Order` spelled `Ordre`. It hurts a little bit.

Comment: Are you setting the dataContext before filling up the OrderList?

Comment: I agree with MBen that it could be the issue. Try using an `ObservableCollection<Ordre>` instead of a `List<Ordre>`.

Comment: @Tyrsius: Sry about the spelling. It's in danish.

Comment: @MBen: I think you are on to something.

Comment: Can you post how you dataContext looks like?

Comment: @MBen: I've tried setting the DataContext to my Collection on the grid that holds my ListView. But still no luck. I have no problems adding items to my collection and showing them in messageboxes. But when it comes to showing them in my listview, nothing happens. It keeps showing up empty.

Comment: I saw that you have a line in the XAML declaring the OrderList but it is empty there, try to delete that line, why did you add it there?

Comment: <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource OrdreList}">
  <ListView IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="Binding}">
     <ListView.View>
<GridView>
 <GridViewColumn Header="Ordredato" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Ordredato}" />
  <GridViewColumn Header="Navn" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=BestiltAf}" />
  <GridViewColumn Header="Ordrenummer" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Ordrereference}" />
 </GridView>
</ListView.View>
                        </ListView>
                    </Grid>

Comment: The OrderList gets filled in my app.cs on startup with public void InitApplication()
        {
            //initialize NotifyIcon
            tb = (TaskbarIcon)FindResource("MyNotifyIcon");
            oc = (OrdreCollection)this.FindResource("OrdreList");            
            oc.fillCollectionFromXml("../../Data/Ordrer.xml");

            //od = (OrdreCollection)this.FindResource("Ordrer");
            //od.fillCollectionFromXml("../../Data/Ordrer.xml");
        }

Comment: I want my OrderCollection to be "globally" available, that's why I put it  there. I just can't get to my objects from my XAML. It's no problem form code-behind.

Comment: I've added it there as a ressource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to my problem. Had to use a CollectionViewSource.

```
<CollectionViewSource 
          Source="{Binding Source={x:Static Application.Current}, Path=OrdreItems}"   
          x:Key="ordreDataView" />
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer after finding it on your own!